# Too many re-renders while setting a state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Getting an error of **Unhandled Runtime Error** while setting a state in an axios get call.
Even tested with a button click and confirmed that function is not called more that once. I don't know what is the problem with it.

Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

```
const [quizzesTaken, setQuizzesTaken] = useState([])

const quizzesTakenByUser = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get('/api/quizzes/quizzestaken')
        setQuizzesTaken(res.data) // Getting error on this line.
    } catch (error) {
        log(error)
    }
}

<button onClick={() => quizzesTakenByUser()}>Get Quizzes</button>

useEffect(() => {
    if (gradeText !== 'none') {
        getGradeDescription()
    }
}, [gradeText])
```

This is how I render the components base on quizzesTaken

```
{quizzesTaken.map(q => {
    return (
        <QuizTakenItem
            subject={
                q.subject +
                ' ' +
                q.class_name
            }
            correct={q.correct_ans}
            total={q.total_questions}
        />
    )
})}
```

Comment: The parts you posted on your question look fine. The problem is maybe somewhere else in the component.

Comment: Can you post eniter code?

Comment: The problem might come from a ```useEffect``` or similar hook and its dependencies set incorrectly. Post the whole code to better understand your problem.

Comment: Most likely you have a `useEffect` somewhere which has `quizzesTaken` as a dependency and which calls `setQuizzesTaken` inside it. Regardless, the problem is not with the code you've shown us here but elsewhere in your component.

Comment: where `gradeText` value you get from?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved after I removed the code setting the independent state of the child component but now it is a more annoying problem to the **brain**, why it was like that is still a question?

```
const [width, setWidth] = useState("10%")
const {correct, total} = props;

setWidth(((correct/total) * 100) + "%")
```

And thank you all for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this way, using `then()` :

```
const [quizzesTaken, setQuizzesTaken] = useState([])

const quizzesTakenByUser = () => {
    axios.get('/api/quizzes/quizzestaken')
        .then(res => setQuizzesTaken(res.data)
        .catch(error => console.log(error)
}

<button onClick={() => quizzesTakenByUser()}>Get Quizzes</button>
```

Comment: Yes, Still getting that same error.

Comment: The error should elsewhere. Did you have a `useEffect` somewhere?

Comment: Yes I have used useEffect but the property there in has no concern with this.

Answer (score -3):

Did you tried like this?

```
<button onClick={quizzesTakenByUser}>Get Quizzes</button>
```